# How to have more than 4 desktop spaces in Ubuntu mate

Tags: 16.04, workspaces, ubuntu-mate

I have a pretty hefty computer and tend to use the extra work spaces a lot. But I want more than 4 because I often run applications in one work space and then switch to the next and run a different application and I tend to run out of space in my work spaces. Is there a way to add 4 more work spaces so I will  have 8? Or am I stuck with 4?

Comment: A description of how to do this from the command-line (even when the GUI control is grayed out): [Ubuntu MATE 18 workspace configuration file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1142245/11522)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to do a right click on the taskbar until the "Add to Panel" option appears (depends on the area you click, usually near the menu is a good place to try) and then choose "Workspace Switcher" from the bottom of the list of the new window. The switcher will appear in the panel and you have to right click on it and select Preferences from the popup menu. Another window will appear and you'll be able to increase the number of workspaces.

[image]

After you're done setting the desired number of workspaces you can remove the switcher from the panel and everything will continue working.

Comment: not in my MATE it won't. It already has a switcher, but the 'number of workspaces' option in the menu is greyed out

Comment: @Zanna - Yes, I saw that this option was for something else and deleted my previous comment. As for your problem - it might be related to some other modification you've done, but what I've described in my answer is tested on a non-modified in any way (except for having the latest updates) clean Ubuntu MATE install in a virtual machine.

Comment: Workspace Switcher works for 4 workspaces but the Preferences menu with number of workspaces is not working on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Mate 1.22.1. All stock, plain vanilla installations with latest updates.

Preferences | Number of workspaces comes up and says 1. Changing it has no effect. Changing Show all workspaces in N rows does work, so something is connected but the N_workspaces is not.

No workee

Comment: tested, works with Ubuntu Mate 22.04