# Ubuntu MATE 18 workspace configuration file?

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, ubuntu-mate

**Where is the configuration file for Ubuntu MATE desktop workspaces?**

I mean the file (or files) that stores information about number of desktops, naming, and spatial arrangement of desktop workspaces (above, below, etc.).

Using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physically the settings are saved in `~/.config/dconf/user`, you need `gsettings` and/or `dconf` to read/write values to this file.

Below is the list of GUI options and their corresponding CLI equivalent:

1. **Switcher**

   - **[ ] Show only the current workspace**  (default is `false`)

     ```
     dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/workspace-switcher/prefs/display-all-workspaces 'false'
     ```
   - **[o] Show all workspaces in** `N` **rows** (default is `1` row):

     ```
     dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/workspace-switcher/prefs/display-all-workspaces 'true'
     dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/workspace-switcher/prefs/num-rows 1
     ```
2. **Workspaces**

   - **Number of workspaces** (default is `4`)

     ```
     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general num-workspaces 4
     ```
   - **Workspace names**

     ```
     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.workspace-names name-1 'Workspace 1'
     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.workspace-names name-2 'Workspace 2'
     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.workspace-names name-3 'Workspace 3'
     gsettings set org.mate.Marco.workspace-names name-4 'Workspace 4'
     ```
   - **[ ] Show workspace names in switcher** (default is `false`)

     ```
     dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/workspace-switcher/prefs/display-workspace-names 'false'
     ```
   - **[ ] Allow workspace wrap around in switcher** (default is `false`)

     ```
     dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/workspace-switcher/prefs/wrap-workspaces 'false'
     ```

Comment: do you know by any chance, where the workspace direction (vertical or horizontal) is stored?    
I always have to show+hide again my sidebar (which contains a vertical workspace switcher) to „tell“ Mate, that I want them vertically aligned (and the respective shortcuts for vertical switching to work.